# How to make responsive images with media tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My responsive div tag have these ul and li. I have a css to set the background of a tag.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="#" id="Feature1"  ></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="Feature2"  ></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {      
    #Feature1{background: url('../img/Feature1.png');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: 60px auto;
       display: inline-block;width:60px;height:30px;}
    }
```

a tag background image is not resizing.

I have tried with 100% width and height of a tag but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: anchor tag background images should be responsive for all screen while re-sizing window

Comment: Instead of using px use %

Comment: i have already tried this: 
#Feature1{background: url('../img/Feature1.png');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: 100% auto;
       display: inline-block;width:100%;height:100%;}

Comment: Not sure if you've tried it before, but I find `background-size: cover;` to be extremely helpful when I'm trying to make my background images responsive.

Comment: use `background:cover;` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike the comments here, I don't think your problem is with background-size, but with your a-element. I *think* your intended result is to automatically adjust the height depending on it's width.

You could solve that problem like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {      
  #Feature1{
    background: url('../img/Feature1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
  }
}
```

Since vertical padding is relative to element width. So 60x30 ratio means `padding-bottom: 50%` and if you have a square image you would use `padding-bottom: 100%`;

Personally, I would go for a `<img>` tag here since it's much easier to get the parent-element to automatically adjust to it (it's even the default behaviour).

Comment: Why do you use padding-bottom here? please explain

Comment: It's impossible adjust an elements size depending on it's background' size. So either you define several media-query steps with static calculated values for each step, or you make the height dependant on the element width, and using vertical padding is a reliable way of doing so...

Comment: thanks, you saved my time i was about to define several media-query.
Still i have problem, while i am re-sizing from vertical, images are not still responsive. instead of while re-sizing from horizontal it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="#" id="Feature1"  >
      <img src="./link/to/img" alt="...">      
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="Feature2"  >
      <img src="./link/to/img" alt="...">
    </a></li>
</ul>

//so it will display a responsive image only 480px bellow
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
  a[id*="Feature"] img{
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

//so it does not display the image anywhere else
a[id*="Feature"] img{
  display:none;
}
```

So all images inside an **anchor** which contains an id of (Feature) no matter if is 1, 2, 3... will display a responsive image..

**Hope this answer your question** T04435.

Comment: anchor tag background image required not img tag

Comment: Yes, thats true but for the css Im not using background-img, Thanks for the comment. @AmitArya

Comment: i wanna use background-img only

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

The simplest technique for adapting images to small screens is to include the following CSS rule in your media query:

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Enter the  element. Proposed to be a part of HTML5, the  element is a solution that is both complete and in need of no additional scripts or third-party services to do the job.

The syntax is as follows:

```
 <picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 64em)" src="high-res.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 37.5em)" src="med-res.jpg">
   <source src="low-res.jpg">
   <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="This picture loads on non-supporting browsers.">
   <p>Accessible text.</p>
</picture>
```